# Переместить последний символ в начало строки

Tags: python

```
def last_to_first(s):
"""
Переместить последний символ в начало строки.
last_to_first("ab") => "ba"
last_to_first("") => ""
last_to_first("hello") => "ohell"
"""
```

При попытке сделать такой код, он выдает ошибку на второй проверке. Что может быть не так?
`result = s[-1:] + s[:-1] return result`

```
assert last_to_first("ab") == "ba"
assert last_to_first("") == ""
assert last_to_first("hello") == "ohell"
```

Answer (score 0):

да вроде все корректно, у меня в pyCharm нормально отработал и с пустой строкой

можно попробовать отдельно обработать этот случай, типа

```
return (s[-1:] + s[:-1]) if len(s) > 0 else ""
```

ошибка выхода за пределы будет если сделать так:

```
s[-1] + s[:-1]
```

и вот для этого случая реально нужна проверка на то, что строка не пустая